# How to generate many wallet addresses from a parent address using pycoin

Tags: python, django, bitcoinlib

I'm new to pycoin which is a python library for bitcoin and other alt-coins and couldn't get my head around it well yet.

I'm working on a project requiring a parent address with many child addresses that could be used to receive coins via django.

For example, Address A would be able to create child 1, child 2 and child 3 .....

and those children could be used to receive coins that will go straight to the parent's Address A

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? It seems it has command line program `ku` which can create child keys. You could check [source code](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/main/pycoin/cmds/ku.py) to see how it works.